# Advice on converting ISO-8859-1 data to UTF-8 in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

We have a very large InnoDB MySQL 5.1 database with all tables using the `latin1_swedish_ci` collation. We want to convert all of the data which *should* be in ISO-8859-1 into UTF-8. How effective would changing the collation to `utf8_general_ci` be, if at all?

Would we be better off writing a script to convert the data and inserting into a new table? Obviously our goal is to minimise the risk of losing any data when re-encoding.

**Edit:** We do have accented character's, £ symbols etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is currently using only latin characters and you are just wanted to change the character set and collation to UTF8 to enable future addition of UTF-8 data, then there should be no problem simply changing the character set and collation.  I would do it in a copy of the table first of course.

Comment: In MySQL you have to change the encoding for the database AND every table AND every column in each table. Unless scripted, a very annoying task.

Comment: We have characters in there with accent codes, this is not latin I assume?

Comment: Those do exist in the latin character set. You should be bale to see them in your database right now.

Comment: Also you don't HAVE to change the database or even table levels settings.  Those just indicate the default character set and collations that will be used if the user does not specify the character sets specifically when defining a table (in case of DB-level setting) or field (in-case of table-level setting).  You can have mixed character sets and collations within the same table.  Note that the approach of simply changing EVERYTHING to UTF-8 has significant implications with regards to storage requirements, as this will make all strings in the entire system take at least twice as much space.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I fully agree. One must change only the fields containing data needed to be stored in unicode. I made a mistake with my first comment. +1

Answer (score 1):

About a week ago I had to do the same task (issues with `ö, ä, å`)

1. Created a `dump.sql`.
2. Searched and replaced all `CHARSET=latin1` **to** `CHARSET=utf8` (in the `dump.sql`).
3. searched and replaced all `COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci` **to** `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` (in the `dump.sql`).
4. Created a new database with the collation `utf8_unicode_ci`.
5. Imported the `dump.sql`.
6. Altered the the database's `charset` with `alter database MY_DB charset=utf8;`

and it worked perfectly

Note: after Mike Brant's remark, I think it's better better to do manual searching and replace for the fields you specifically want. Or you can simply use `ALTER` for each field without needing the `dump.sql`. It didn't make much change in my case, as most of my fields needed to be utf  encoded